# Evernote - OAuth access token - Python

Tags: python, oauth, evernote

I am going through [Evernote OAuth](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php) documentation. Was not able to get the temp token. It was resolved after receiving help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510907/evernote-access-token-python). Now, struck at the last step of this flow while receiving Access token. Could you someone let me know what could be the potential issue here?

Its following the similar below to the first one to retrieve the access token. Not sure if there is anything I miss.

```
import time
import base64
import random
import uuid
import urllib
import collections
import urllib.parse
import hmac
import hashlib
import binascii
import requests

def escape(s):
    return urllib.parse.quote(s, safe='~')
def get_nonce():
    return uuid.uuid4().hex

def stringify_parameters(parameters):
    output = ''
    ordered_parameters = {}
    ordered_parameters =collections.OrderedDict(sorted(parameters.items()))

    counter = 1
    for k, v in ordered_parameters.items():
        output += escape(str(k)) + '=' + escape(str(v))
        if counter < len(ordered_parameters):
            output += '&'
            counter += 1

    return output

oauth_parameters={
'oauth_timestamp': str(int(time.time())),
'oauth_signature_method': "HMAC-SHA1",
'oauth_version': "1.0",
'oauth_nonce': get_nonce(),
'oauth_consumer_key': 'xxxxx',
'oauth_callback':'http://localhost'
 }

string_parameters=stringify_parameters(oauth_parameters)
secret='3************f'

### below portion of the code will return temp_token
key = (escape(secret)+'&').encode()
message = ('GET&' + escape('https://sandbox.evernote.com/oauth') + '&' + escape(string_parameters)).encode()
signature = hmac.new(key, message, hashlib.sha1).digest()
oauth_parameters['oauth_signature'] = base64.b64encode(signature).decode()

print(stringify_parameters(oauth_parameters))

res = requests.get('https://sandbox.evernote.com/oauth?' + stringify_parameters(oauth_parameters))
print(res.text)
####

##login to the url below based on the temp_token from above
##https://sandbox.evernote.com/OAuth.action?oauth_token=xxxxx.1652F9812D6.687474703A2F2F6C6F63616C686F7374.3A695C3760E6EFB92B3AB6033222E9D7

## after successful authorization from user, page is redirected along with 'oauth_verifier' value
##http://localhost/?oauth_token=xxxxx.1652F9812D6.687474703A2F2F6C6F63616C686F7374.3A695C3760E6EFB92B3AB6033222E9D7&oauth_verifier=1808C99D6868D17A89871E9290B334D6&sandbox_lnb=false

###error part - below doesn't work while retrieving the access token.

oauth_parameters={
'oauth_consumer_key': 'xxxxx',
'oauth_token': 'xxxxx.1652F9812D6.687474703A2F2F6C6F63616C686F7374.3A695C3760E6EFB92B3AB6033222E9D7',
'oauth_verifier':'1808C99D6868D17A89871E9290B334D6',
'oauth_nonce': get_nonce(),
'oauth_signature_method':'HMAC-SHA1',
'oauth_timestamp': str(int(time.time())),
'oauth_version': '1.0'
}

string_parameters=stringify_parameters(oauth_parameters)

key = (escape(secret)+'&').encode()
message = ('GET&' + escape('https://sandbox.evernote.com/oauth') + '&' + escape(string_parameters)).encode()
signature = hmac.new(key, message, hashlib.sha1).digest()

oauth_parameters['oauth_signature'] = 
base64.b64encode(signature).decode()

res = requests.get('https://sandbox.evernote.com/oauth?' + 
stringify_parameters(oauth_parameters))
print(res.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of without knowing what the error message is (if there is any), is whether the oauth_verifier is copied over correctly. Everything else looks like it should work fine.